# trouble getting started with Jinja2 in Google app-engine

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

I am trying to use the jinja2 templates frameworks in google app-engine on windows xp os. I can not get past this Name error. can someone please help?

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
   loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(_file_),'templates')),
   autoescape    = True)

NameError: name '_file_' is not defined
INFO     2012-06-29 12:49:14,640 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `__file__` (with 2 sets of 2 underscores), not `_file_`.

Comment: WoW im such a noob. i feel dumb. thanks for your reply it really got me going and not the site is online, very much appreciated. TY